# Is it possible to access clearcase view private files from just the view storage directory?

Tags: clearcase

I have a machine that is misbehaving (dns and thus clearcase isn't working at the moment).  I was hoping to access the checked out files I had in that view (and a few other view private files) and start over my work on another machine while I wait for the IT admin guys to come back to work tomorrow.

Is is possible to get at my checked out files from just the view storage directory (i.e. ~/views/peeterj_gcc6.vws/...)?

i.e. find in the viewstorage dir shows lots of paths that are surely my view private files:

```
./.s/00019/8000149553ab76a5fontconfig.Turbo.bfc
./.s/00019/80003d3353ac5afftestinc_Subpool.compilecmd
./.s/00019/8000445a53ac65b3sqlnlscnvtbls6-LE.u
./.s/00019/8000045e53ab62eccdeSystemPageInterface.hpp
./.s/00019/8000556053ac934ftestinc_sqlhhid.C
```

but I'm not sure how to map from these to the original file names within the view.

EDIT:

I was able to brute force this task, where ~/tmp/f2 contained a list of the files of interest:

```
cd ~/views/peeterj_gcc6.vws/
for i in `cat ~/tmp/f2` ; do echo $i `find .  -name "*$i"` ; done | grep ' ' | f.pl
```

where f.pl is the following perl filter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $vsdir = "$ENV{HOME}/views/peeterj_gcc6.vws" ;

while (<>)
{
   chomp ;

   my ($f, @rest) = split( / /, $_ ) ;

   my @match = () ;

   foreach my $p (@rest)
   {
      if ( $p =~ m,/[0-9a-f]+$f$, )
      {
         push( @match, $p ) ;

         goto DONE ; # hack.  Just pick first.
      }
   }

   if ( scalar(@match) )
   {
DONE:
      print "cp $vsdir/@match $f\n" ;
   }
}
```

So, I'll re-pose the question: Is there a way to systematically map the names of the files in the view storage directory to the paths that they would be in in the view when clearcase is functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to systematically map the names of the files in the view storage directory to the paths that they would be in in the view when ClearCase is functional?
>
> Not really consistently, not even for their *name*.

If you look at the IBM technote "[Locating view private files in the storage directory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146208)", their advice is:

> Go into the `.s` sub-directory
>
> Located under this directory are many numbered directories.
>   Browse through the numbered directories, searching for the view-private file.
>   All the files that are listed in these directories are view-private files. The file names of the files will be preceded by an ID number.
>
> Example:
>
> The view private file, `help.txt`, in the directory under `.s`, is named

```
241ae3df.000c.help.txt
```

> Note: **View private files that have been renamed in the view are not renamed in the view storage directory**.
>   For instance, if you create a view private file called `help.txt`, and then you rename it to `new.txt`, the physical file in the view storage directory would still be named `241ae3df.000c.help.txt`

So if you had *another* *working* view, you could try and copy the files you find in the old view storage one in a similar path in the new view storage, and see if that works.